# i want to read a call log history

Tags: java-me, nokia

I want to read call log history in j2me. Is it possible?
If yes, how to do it ?

Comment: You should better search the Nokia SDK documentation for this. There you will found the better and in depth solution.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Its not possible in j2me.

But i seen this [nokia forum](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?214801-Getting-Call-history-in-J2ME). They achieved by using some third party API. You can try with that sample.

Comment: i know that in case of j2me call log access is not possible ,but how to possible by third party...please describe details....

Comment: I didn't achieved before. See that link, clearly described in that site.